# Floor and square root function equation : $\lfloor {\sqrt x}\rfloor = \sqrt {\lfloor x \rfloor}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Source :  Lycée Berthelot's higher mathematics exercices ( https://molin-mathematiques.fr/sources/exercices106.php)

Note : definitely *not* HW

To be solved :   $\space \lfloor {\sqrt x}\rfloor = \sqrt {\lfloor x \rfloor}$

My reasoning so far:

From  $\lfloor {\sqrt x}\rfloor = \sqrt {\lfloor x \rfloor}$

we can deduce

(1) that $x\geq 0$

(2) $\sqrt {\lfloor x \rfloor} \in \mathbb Z$ and is a positive integer by definition ( since a square root is always positive).

(3) since only squares of integers have integral square roots, we have $\lfloor x \rfloor = p^2$ with $p\in \mathbb Z$

(4) $p^2 \leq x \lt p^2 +1$, for some $p \in \mathbb Z$.

> The conclusion I seem to reach is that the solution set is the set of
> all $x$ such that $x$ is greater or equal to some number that is the square of an integer , meaning
> that the solution set is the set of all positive real numbers ( with $0$).

But ***in fact, according to Desmos, the graphs of the LHS and of the RHS function seem never to cross oneanother***, suggesting that the solution set is empty.

What do I miss?

Desmos :

[image]

Comment: $x$ is a solution to the equation if and only if there is some integer $p$ such that $p^2\le x<p^2+1$. Why you would infer that this is the case for all $x$ in $\Bbb R$ is beyond my understanding (and it's wrong anyways, so why bother?). As far as Desmos goes, either it is wrong or you are wrong in reading it. I think you are, but it's red over green so I would not bet my head on it.

Comment: To better see what is happening, you could plot the graph of $\lfloor {\sqrt x}\rfloor - \sqrt {\lfloor x \rfloor}$

Comment: @MasB.- I've just plotted the graph , and see that the graph is not identical to $y=0$
 as is to be expected if one wants to say that the solution set is the set of all real positive numbers. So is my " solution " above to be corrected?

Comment: @VinceVickler Yes your "solution" needs to be adjusted. It consists only of the intervals $[k^2,k^2+1)$ for all choices of the integer $k \ge 0.$ [of course the $k=0,1$ cases have no gap between them, so that part is really $[0,2).$ for larger $k$ these half-open intervals have gaps betweenm them.] Suggestion for graphics: make say the green graph shift up a bit by adding say $0.1$ to its formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't missed anything except that when Desmos plots the graph and the two functions agree the green is plotted on top of the red.  You claimed, for example, that when $1 \le x \lt 2$ both functions evaluate to $1$, which is correct.  You can see the green curve is constant at $1$ over that interval and you cannot see the red curve because it is under the green curve.  Again for $4 \le x \lt 5$ both functions evaluate to $2$ and again they are plotted on top of each other.

Comment: I first thought that the solution set was $R+$ , but now it seems to me that the solution set is the union of all intervals of the form $[a, a+1)$ with $a$, a perfect square. Would you say that this constitutes an acceptable solution?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  That is how I read your point (4) initially, which is what I was agreeing with.